# Optimisation of Scala's for-comprehension (identity map)

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

How can I avoid a `map(identity)` in Scala `for`-comprehensions?

For example, consider:

```scala
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Test extends App {
  implicit val executorContext = ExecutionContext.global
  val future = Future.successful { 1 }
  val result = for (
    value <- future;
    b <- Future { value * 2 }
  ) yield b
  println(Await.result(result, 60 seconds))
}
```

IIUC, the `for`-comprehension translates to something like

```scala
future.flatMap(value => Future { value * 2 }).map(identity)
```

Can I avoid the trailing `map(identity)` in some way? Or does/can/could Scala optimise it away? (I suppose it cannot as it is not clear whether `map` has any side effects, right?)

P.S. I know that in this particular example, things can be improved. I am wondering about the general case, where for instance `Future { value * 2}` is a call `f(value)` to a function `f` returning a future.

Comment: It is quite bold assumption that there will be `.map(identity)` after for-comprehension translation

Comment: For comprehensions doesn't calls a `.map(identity)`. just run a scalac -Xprint:typer to see for yourself.

Comment: Is it me or this is an "abuse" of syntactic sugar when you can write something like `val result = future.map( _ * 2)` ?

Comment: after `scalac -Xprint:parser`, you get: `(...) 
val result = future.flatMap(((value) => Future(value.$times(2)).map(((b) => b)))); (...)`
@pedrofurla, what version of scala are you using ?

Comment: @BGR: I don't think syntactic sugar is particularly abusable even in principle. And the syntactic sugar that is Scala's `for` comprehension is spectacularly helpful for clarifying source code after just the first or second generator or filter.

Comment: @RandallSchulz In principle, I agree with you on syntactic sugar but the for/yield comprehension conveys a meaning that "I want to chain monadic operations" when all you are trying to achieve in this example is "I want to perform a calculation on a future result" which in my view is better expressed by a simple `map`

Comment: @BGR: For single applications of any of the monadic HOFs, I agree. But for all but the simplest such expressions, the `for` sugar is a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 2):

It's [an anti-pattern](http://twitter.github.com/effectivescala/#Concurrency-Futures) to create your own Future just to operate applicatively inside one. You can instead:

- `future.map()` and finally get your result with `onSuccess` (this is the simplest model)
- if you are dead set on comprehensions, `yield Future { value * 2 }` and then get your result ... (though this doesn't solve the spurious Future creation problem)
- `transform` your Future and then get your result ...
- `collect` on your future and then `map(f)` on results

Depending on your context and computation model, one or another of these solutions might more appropriate : you seem to be presenting a specific case of a general situation, but it's unclear if the general situation should involve iterating over Futures, chaining transformations in one Future, or something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks, @huitseeker, for your comments on this particular use case involving futures, very useful. However, as you say, I was trying to present an example for a general observation: namely that such monadic expressions are compiled by Scala to function calls, where the last one is `map(identify)`. I am wondering whether this could be optimised away? For, in some monads, the latter call might be expensive.